# Delphi loading TImage from CreateBlobStream ADO Query

Tags: delphi

I have been trying to load image data stored in a varbinary mssql column to a TImage component using the code below, but it gives an error

```
 with Query_Refresh do
   Begin
     close;
     open;
     if RecordCount > 0 then
       Begin
         //Edit to allow the streaming of the fields
         Edit;

         //MyStream is of Type TStream
         MyStream := CreateBlobStream(FieldByName('MyBlobField'),bmWrite);

         //Loading to the image --- Error occurs on the line below
         MyImage.Picture.Graphic.LoadFromStream(MyStream);
       End;
   End;
```

Error is Access violation....

Please someone assist on how to do this

Comment: Access violation, means that you are trying to access a object that do not exists. which line is the error happening? FieldByName('MyBlobField') returns the instance of MyBLobField? I suggest you to remove your "with Query_Refresh do", it will make debug harder.

Comment: First, I'd get rid of the `with` statement and replace it with an explaining variable. Which line does the access violation occur on?

Comment: Error occured when trying to load the TStream to the Timage object

Comment: @Ceasar MyBlobField is just the name of the varbinary field in the database

Comment: The second thing I'd get rid of (after `with`) is the `RecordCount > 0`, which is very very slow and inefficient. TADOQuery inherits `IsEmpty` from `TDataSet`, and while `RecordCount` has to retrieve all the rows in order to find out how many there are, `IsEmpty` just sees if there's at least 1.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to get the data in the query to the TImage component

Comment: shouldn't it be bmRead rather than bmWrite?

Comment: Your `MyImage.Picture.Graphic` is nil?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TPicture` does not hold a `TGraphic` unless you tell it to. It starts out empty, so the `Graphic` property is null. That's why you get an access violation when you try to call methods on it.

If you don't already know what kind of graphic you've stored, you'll either have to write something that inspects the contents of the field to figure it out, or add another field to your database that describes the format of the graphic field.

Once you know what kind of graphic you have, you can create an instance of that class, load it from the stream, and assign it to the `TPicture` container. Free your graphic afterward since `TPicture` creates its own copy of the graphic. Here's an example:

```
var
  DBGraphicClass: TGraphicClass;
  Graphic: TGraphic;

// Implementing FieldValToGraphicClass is an exercise for the reader.
DBGraphicClass := FieldValToGraphicClass(FieldByName('MyBlobFieldType'));
Graphic := DBGraphicClass.Create;
try
  Graphic.LoadFromStream(MyStream);
  MyImage.Picture.Graphic := Graphic;
finally
  Graphic.Free;
end;
```

If the known type is always one of the graphic properties that `TPicture` already has, then you can access the type-specific property directly and skip the step of allocating your own graphic object. For example, if your database holds bitmaps, then you can access `TPicture.Bitmap` instead of `TPicture.Graphic`. Then `TPicture` will create a `TBitmap` object automatically. For example:

```
MyImage.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(MyStream);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `MyImage.Picture.Graphic.Assign(Graphic);`? Or is the `MyImage.Picture.Graphic := Graphic;` method an equivalent of the former in this case?

Comment: It's the same thing, @Andriy. Look in `TPicture.SetGraphic` and see for yourself.

Comment: Ah, I see. *Almost* the same, though, as it `Assign`s the argument to a *new* `TGraphic` instance (which is then stored into the field behind the property). Anyway, it must be better, given they decided to implement it using so many steps. Thanks for bringing that to my attention!

Comment: Yes, that too, @Andriy. In fact, that's the point of my answer. You *must* assign to the `Graphic` property because calling `Graphic.Assign` will fail for the same reason calling `Graphic.LoadFromStream` fails.