# Delphi 7-How to save pictures in a database

Tags: database, delphi, ms-access, save, delphi-7

I have been trying to create a select-your-picture-and-upload function of a normal user's profile in Delphi 7, but I am running in some problems.

Basically what I want is the following:

- User uploads a picture from a folder (which I have achieved through a normal 
  OpenPictureDialog component)
- Said picture gets stored in a database, which is where I'm stuck.

The database is a normal access database.
The table has a unique ID to identify the members and next to that is the picture of each member on the "Picture field" (which is set as a BLOB object).

So in other words my question is the following:
What components do I need to use in order to save a picture to a specified place in my database?

I have found some random code in the net but I'm running into troubles understanding what it does.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825513/delphi-loading-timage-from-createblobstream-ado-query

Comment: Since you might get in trouble storing and loading different image formats without knowing the TGraphicClass needed for reloading you might consider adding information about the needed format. [retrieve image saved on database](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14726934/1699210)

Answer (score 2):

```
ADOQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT PictureField FROM YourTable';
ADOQuery.Open();
ADOQuery.Edit();

TBlobField(ADOQuery.FieldByName('PictureField')).LoadFromFile('PathToPictureFile');

ADOQuery.Post();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use imageEn component.
[Web Site url to get information and download trial](http://www.imageen.com/)